# Angular img scr displaying cache image

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 9 and have a question page where users can upload images for each question. When they do, they can instantly see the uploaded image. The [src] of the image always changes each time an image is uploaded. When the user enters question data and adds an image (uploads) sometimes a previous image is displayed even though the src path is correctly pointing towards the newly uploaded image -> if the user right-clicks the image and selects "Open image in new tab" it will correctly show the latest uploaded image and not the (cached) image displayed.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you prepare a stackblitz example?

Comment: is the url the same for the old image and the new one?

Answer (score 0):

For this case use state management method and dispatch every time when new image is uploaded, and get it from the store for displaying new images.

Refer this document:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/state-management-in-angular-with-ngxs/

Dispatch like this as each time when image is being uploaded.
this.store.dispatch(new AddProduct(this.img.list));

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. The problem was related to the upload control which allowed multiple files to be uploaded at a time. Even though I was only allowing one file to be uploaded I needed to reinitialise the upload file array (to be  = []) after each file was uploaded. Thanks again for your answers much appreciated.